# ZeroMQ Pub-Sub implement privileges for specific topics for specific subscribers

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

Is it possible, in ZeroMQ Pub-Sub model, to filter out (disallow) some topic for specific subscribers for security reasons? If not, what other pattern could match such architecture?

Comment: Why is this tagged C and C++? Your question appears to depend on ZeroMQ, not C or C++.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way to get what you want -- while still using pub/sub sockets -- would be to create an `xpub/xsub` proxy server. You'd have a structure something like:

[image]

Privileged clients connecto the upstream publisher, while "restricted" clients connect through the proxy.

Here's an example proxy implementation in Python; a C/C++ solution would use similar logic:

```
import zmq
import random
import time

ctx = zmq.Context()
upstream = ctx.socket(zmq.XSUB)
downstream = ctx.socket(zmq.XPUB)

upstream.connect("tcp://localhost:3000")
downstream.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:3001")

poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(upstream, zmq.POLLIN)
poller.register(downstream, zmq.POLLIN)

secret_topics = ["topic3"]

while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll())
    if upstream in socks and socks[upstream] == zmq.POLLIN:
        msg = upstream.recv_multipart()

        # We've received a messages from the upstream
        # publisher. Let's see if we should block it...
        if msg[0].decode() in secret_topics:
            # It's a secret message, don't publish it to
            # our subscribers!
            print("upstream !!", msg)
            continue

        # If we get this far, publish the message to our
        # subscribers.
        print("upstream ->", msg)
        downstream.send_multipart(msg)
    elif downstream in socks and socks[downstream] == zmq.POLLIN:
        # This is a message FROM the subscibers TO the
        # publisher (i.e., a subscription message)
        msg = downstream.recv_multipart()
        print("downstream ->", msg)
        upstream.send_multipart(msg)
```

A `SUB` socket client will connect to this instead of the publisher, and the proxy will filter out messages that have topics matching an item in `secret_topics`.

The next question becomes, "how do I prevent the client from connecting to the upstream publisher?", to which the answer is probably to implement [authentication](https://rfc.zeromq.org/spec/27/) so that only authorized clients can connect to the upstream publisher, and everything else connects to the filtering proxy (or require different auth for the proxy).